# Using SQL to transpose/flatten XML structure to columns

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, pivot, xquery-sql

I am using SQL Server (2008/2012) and I know there are similar answers from lots of searching, however I can't seem to find the appropriate example/pointers for my case.

I have an XML column in a SQL Server table holding this data:

```
<Items>
 <Item>
  <FormItem>
    <Text>FirstName</Text>
    <Value>My First Name</Value>
  </FormItem>
  <FormItem>
    <Text>LastName</Text>
    <Value>My Last Name</Value>
  </FormItem>
  <FormItem>
    <Text>Age</Text>
    <Value>39</Value>
  </FormItem>
 </Item>
 <Item>
  <FormItem>
    <Text>FirstName</Text>
    <Value>My First Name 2</Value>
  </FormItem>
  <FormItem>
    <Text>LastName</Text>
    <Value>My Last Name 2</Value>
  </FormItem>
  <FormItem>
    <Text>Age</Text>
    <Value>40</Value>
  </FormItem>
 </Item>
</Items>
```

So even though the structure of `<FormItem>` is going to be the same, I can have multiple (most commonly no more than 20-30) sets of form items..

I am essentially trying to return a query from SQL in the format below, i.e. dynamic columns based on /FormItem/Text:

```
FirstName         LastName         Age    ---> More columns as new `<FormItem>` are returned
My First Name     My Last Name     39          Whatever value etc..
My First Name 2   My Last Name 2   40
```

So, at the moment I had the following:

```
select 
    Tab.Col.value('Text[1]','nvarchar(100)') as Question,
    Tab.Col.value('Value[1]','nvarchar(100)') as Answer
from
    @Questions.nodes('/Items/Item/FormItem') Tab(Col)
```

Of course that hasn't transposed my XML rows into columns, and obviously is fixed with fields anyway.. I have been trying various "Dynamic SQL" approaches where the SQL performs a distinct selection of (in my case) the `<Text>` node, and then uses some sort of Pivot? but I couldn't seem to find the magic combination to return the results I need as a dynamic set of columns for each row (`<Item>` within the collection of `<Items>`).

I'm sure it can be done having seen so many very similar examples, however again the solution eludes me!

Any help gratefully received!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parsing the XML is fairly expensive so instead of parsing once to build a dynamic query and once to get the data you can create a temporary table with a Name-Value list and then use that as the source for a dynamic pivot query.
`dense_rank` is there to create the ID to pivot around.
To build the column list in the dynamic query it uses the `for xml path('')` trick.

This solution requires that your table has a primary key (ID). If you have the XML in a variable it can be somewhat simplified.

```sql
select dense_rank() over(order by ID, I.N) as ID,
       F.N.value('(Text/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)') as Name,
       F.N.value('(Value/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)') as Value
into #T
from YourTable as T
  cross apply T.XMLCol.nodes('/Items/Item') as I(N)
  cross apply I.N.nodes('FormItem') as F(N)

declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
declare @Col nvarchar(max)

select @Col = 
  (
  select distinct ','+quotename(Name)
  from #T
  for xml path(''), type
  ).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'nvarchar(max)')

set @SQL = 'select '+@Col+'
            from #T
            pivot (max(Value) for Name in ('+@Col+')) as P'

exec (@SQL)

drop table #T
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2a88/2)

Comment: Thanks! works just as I needed.. Actually I have another level above the example shown, but then that is really to group <Items> together.. but the key part is to show the variable xml nodes <Items><Item> as columns with repeating rows of <Items>.. so many thanks for a very detailed example!

Answer (score 3):

```
select Tab.Col.value('(FormItem[Text = "FirstName"]/Value)[1]', 'varchar(32)') as FirstName, 
        Tab.Col.value('(FormItem[Text = "LastName"]/Value)[1]', 'varchar(32)') as LastName, 
        Tab.Col.value('(FormItem[Text = "Age"]/Value)[1]', 'int') as Age
from @Questions.nodes('/Items/Item') Tab(Col)
```

Comment: Thanks, good example and actually hadn't seen that technique much before, however it doesn't display the fields dynamically across as columns - probably ok if you knew the amount of columns in advance, however the above example from @Mikael does what I need - nevertheless, thanks for replying and again very simple clean example for sure.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add my "own answer" really just for completeness to possibly help others.. however it is most definitely based on the great help from @Mikael above!!  so again, this is really for completeness only - all kudos to @Mikael.

Basically I ended up with the following proc.  I needed to select some data/filter, and get some joined data too and allow some boolean filtering on some of the input params.  Then drop into the next section which was create a temp table of my relational data and the required xml nodes via the cross apply.  The final step was to then pivot the results/dynamically create the columns from the selected XML node..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_RPT_ExtractFlattenentries]
    @CompanyID          int,
    @MainSelector       nvarchar(50) = null,
    @SecondarySelector      nvarchar(255) = null,
    @DateFrom           datetime = '01-jan-2012',
    @DateTo             datetime = '31-dec-2100',
    @SysReference       nvarchar(20) = null
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --  Create the table var to hold the XML form data from the entries
    declare @FeedbackXml table (
        ID int identity primary key,
        XMLCol xml,
        CompanyName nvarchar(20),
        SysReference nvarchar(20),
        RecordDate datetime,
        EntryName  nvarchar(255),
        MainSelector nvarchar(50)
    )

    --  STEP 1: Get the raw submission data based on the params passed in
    --  *Note: The double casting is necessary as the "form" field is nvarchar (not varchar) and we need xml in UTF-8 format
    begin
        insert into @FeedbackXml
            (XMLCol, CompanyName, SysReference, RecordDate, EntryName, MainSelector)
        select cast(cast(e.form as nvarchar(max)) as xml), c.name, e.SysReference, e.RecordDate, e.name, e.wizard
        from 
            entries s
        left join
            companies o on e.companies = c.ID
        where 
            (@CompanyID = -1 or @CompanyID = e.companies)
        and
            (@MainSelector is null or @MainSelector = e.wizard)
        and
            (@SecondarySelector is null or @SecondarySelector = e.name)
        and
            (@SysReference is null or @SysReference = e.SysReference)
        and
            (e.RecordDate >= @DateFrom and e.RecordDate <= @DateTo)
    end

    --  STEP 2: Flatten the required XML structure to provide a base for the pivot, and include other fields we wish to output
    select dense_rank() over(order by ID) as ID,
            T.RecordDate, T.CompanyName, T.SysReference, T.EntryName, T.MainSelector,
            F.N.value('(FieldNameNode/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as FieldName,
            F.N.value('(FieldNameValue/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as FieldValue
    into #TempData
    from @FeedbackXml as T
        cross apply T.XMLCol.nodes('/root/companies/') as I(N) -- Xpath to the desired node start point
        cross apply I.N.nodes('company') as F(N) -- The actual node collection that forms the "field name" and "field value" data

    --  STEP 3: Pivot the #TempData table creating a dynamic column structure based on the selected XML nodes in step 2
    declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
    declare @Col nvarchar(max)

    select @Col = 
      (
      select distinct ','+quotename(FieldName)
      from #TempData
      for xml path(''), type
      ).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'nvarchar(max)')

    set @SQL = 'select CompanyName, SysReference, EntryName, MainSelector, RecordDate, '+@Col+'
                from #TempData
                pivot (max(FieldValue) for FieldName in ('+@Col+')) as P'

    exec (@SQL)
    drop table #TempData

END
```

Again, really only added this answer to provide a complete picture from my perspective, and may help others.